# How to find how many times a word appears in a array? Python

Tags: python, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [item frequency count in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python)

Quick question

How do you find how many times a word appears in an array?

I have an array that has around 5000 words of text, and i want to find how many times the word "help" appears in the array. How do i do this?

the array is stored in x, so my code looks like this:

```
x = [...]
word = "help"
```

and then i dont know what to put to get the number of times "help" appears in x

thank you for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us the code you have up to now so that we can help you better.

Comment: is each of the 5000 words an own entry in the array?

Comment: I havent tried any code because i dont know how i would do it.

Comment: and the array is like ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'.... etc]

Comment: See the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python

Comment: so you want to count occurrence of ['h','e','l','p',]  ??

Comment: In addition, if you actually have it as a list instead of a string, you can turn it into a string with "".join(MyArray)

Comment: Added [tag:homework] to the post (can't imagine it to be anything else).

Comment: Are the words separated by a space?

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import collections
>>> print collections.Counter(['a', 'word', 'is', 'a', 'thing', 'that', 'is', 'countable'])
Counter({'a': 2, 'is': 2, 'word': 1, 'that': 1, 'countable': 1, 'thing': 1})
```

This is 2.7+, a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Based on your edit, where each element in the list is a letter instead of the full word, then:

```
>>> import re
>>> letters = 
['i', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'd', 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'a', 's', 'e', 'I', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p']
>>> len(re.findall('help', "".join(letters)))
3
```

Comment: +1 for the cleanest and most powerful solution. That still doesn't help him a lot, if this was a homework question and he was meant to do it manually. :-)

Comment: I didn't assume it to be homework, as the tag was not included.  But, point taken.

Answer (score 1):

As @sberry has depicted, Counter would server the purpose, but in case you are only searching a single word once and not interested to get the occurrence of all the words, you can use a simpler tool for the purpose

(I have taken the example from sberry)

Given a list of words to find the occurrence of any given words, you can use the `count` method of the list

```
>>> list_of_words=['a', 'word', 'is', 'a', 'thing', 'that', 'is', 'countable']
>>> list_of_words.count('is')
2
```

As your comments have shown you may be interested to search on a list of characters. Such as

```
letters =
['i', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'd', 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'a', 's', 'e', 'I', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p']
```

You can also use the count on the string after is generated by concatenating all the characters

```
>>> ''.join(letters).count('help')
3
```

In case the words are jumbled, `collections.Counter` ad do magic here

```
>>> def count_words_in_jumbled(jumbled,word):
    jumbled_counter = collections.Counter(jumbled)
    word_counter = collections.Counter(word)
    return min(v /word_counter[k] for k,v in jumbled_counter.iteritems() if k in word)

>>> count_words_in_jumbled(['h','e','l','l','h','e','l','l','h','e','l'],'hel')
3
>>> count_words_in_jumbled(['h','e','l','l','h','e','l','l','h','e','l'],'hell')
2
>>> count_words_in_jumbled(['h','x','e','y','l','u','p'] ,'help')
1
```

Comment: -1 @Abhijit the join() method will not work if the array is like `['h','x','e','y','l','u','p']`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: OP never mentioned that the letters are jumbled. I have also read through the comments but not a pinch of hint indicating the same.

Comment: it looks like you're correct, can't do a +1 my vote is locked until you edit the solution.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I have edited my answer. Check the last part of it :-)

Comment: What is the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
nhelps = len(''.join(charlist).split('help')[1:]
```