# Read list of lists and output as dictionary, the count of values per key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists like this

```
list1=[['a', '2'] ['a', '1'] ['b', '3'] ['c', '2'] ['b', '1'] ['a', '1']['b', '1'] ['c', '2']['b', '3'] ['b', '1']]
```

I want to walk through this and find out number for each first item:

```
a:[2,1,1] b:[3,1,3,1] c:[2,2]
```

Finally it should print the counts of per key and output as a dictionary

```
{'a': 3, 'b':4, 'c':2}
```

The intermediate step need not be outputted.

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [item frequency count in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can definitely be condensed, but you can create a dictionary of each key to a list of each value:

```
d = {}
for key, val in list1:
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = []
    d[key].append(val)
```

Then use a list comprehension along with the dict() constructor for the end result:

```
d2 = dict((k, len(vallist)) for k, vallist in d.iteritems())
```

Comment: This would be better with a `Counter` or even `defaultdict`. This is actually quite an unidiomatic way.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `collections.Counter`:

If I understand correctly, you want to know the number of times each "key" is present.  The following code will do that:

```
d = Counter(x[0] for x in list1)
```

Comment: Hi it is neither, please see the question, I want to get the number of values for each key.  a has values as 2,1,1 b has 3,1,3,1.  I want to get the count of each and output as a:3, b:4, c : 2 as a dictionary(NOT as a list)

Comment: @user1189851 -- Can you be more specific?  How is the number of values different than the number of times the key is present?

Comment: It gives an error:File "coll.py", line 4, in <module>
    list1=[['a', '2'] ['a', '1'] ['b', '3'] ['c', '2'] ['b', '1'] ['a', '1']['b', '1'] ['c', '2']['b', '3'] ['b', '1']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: @user1189851 -- You're missing commas between each sublist.  `list1=[['a','2'],['a','1'],...]`

Comment: This does exactly what the accepted answer does, but in 1/6 of the lines.