# Count word occurrence in a list of strings

Tags: python

How to count how many times a word appears in a list of strings?

For example:

```
['This is a sentence', 'This is another sentence']
```

and the result for the word "sentence" is 2

Comment: Perhaps you could try a loop? And `split()`?

Comment: Could you paste your first attempt that didn't work so we can help you track down the problem?

Comment: Related : [item frequency count in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python)

Comment: "Learn python and stop bothering us." Nice one.

Comment: nice community you got here..perhaps instead of being mean you could try answering the question or freakin' skip it

Comment: You clearly didn't read instructions about making a proper question nor show any effort of trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: sum(i.count('sentence') for i in ['This is a sentence', 'This is another sentence'])

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `collections.Counter()` object and split your words on whitespace. You probably want to lowercase your words as well, and remove punctuation:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()

for sentence in sequence_of_sentences:
    counts.update(word.strip('.,?!"\'').lower() for word in sentence.split())
```

or perhaps use a regular expression that only matches word characters:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

counts = Counter()
words = re.compile(r'\w+')

for sentence in sequence_of_sentences:
    counts.update(words.findall(sentence.lower()))
```

Now you have a `counts` dictionary with per-word counts.

Demo:

```
>>> sequence_of_sentences = ['This is a sentence', 'This is another sentence']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> for sentence in sequence_of_sentences:
...     counts.update(word.strip('.,?!"\'').lower() for word in sentence.split())
... 
>>> counts
Counter({'this': 2, 'is': 2, 'sentence': 2, 'a': 1, 'another': 1})
>>> counts['sentence']
2
```

Comment: Instead of trying to write out all the punctuation symbols, I'd use regex in the first place. `re.findall('\w+', sentence)`

Comment: @OlehPrypin: Oh, yeah, nice idea too.

Comment: @OlehPrypin The problem with that regex is that it doesn't account for words with `-`, it will count as 2 words

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida: then update the regex to include those: `r'[\w-]+'` would count dashes as word characters.

Answer (score 3):

You could do what you want pretty easily with a little regex and a dictionary.

```
import re

dict = {}
sentence_list = ['This is a sentence', 'This is a sentence']
for sentence in sentence_list:
    for word in re.split('\s', sentence): # split with whitespace
        try:
            dict[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
            dict[word] = 1
print dict
```