# Python - Count number of words in a list strings

Tags: python, string, list, counter

Im trying to find the number of whole words in a list of strings, heres the list

```
mylist = ["Mahon Point retail park", "Finglas","Blackpool Mahon", "mahon point  blanchardstown"]
```

expected outcome:

```
4
1
2
3
```

There are 4 words in mylist[0], 1 in mylist[1] and so on

```
for x, word in enumerate(mylist):
    for i, subwords in enumerate(word):
        print i
```

Totally doesnt work....

What do you guys think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count word occurrence in a list of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231542/count-word-occurrence-in-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
>>> mylist = ["Mahon Point retail park", "Finglas","Blackpool Mahon", "mahon point  blanchardstown"] 
>>> for item in mylist:
...     print len(item.split())
...     
4
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way should be

```
num_words = [len(sentence.split()) for sentence in mylist]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/):

```
import nltk
mylist = ["Mahon Point retail park", "Finglas","Blackpool Mahon", "mahon point  blanchardstown"]
print(map(len, map(nltk.word_tokenize, mylist)))
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x,word in enumerate(mylist):
    print len(word.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a="hello world aa aa aa abcd  hello double int float float hello"
words=a.split(" ")
words
dic={}
for word in words:
    if dic.has_key(word):
        dic[word]=dic[word]+1
    else:
        dic[word]=1
dic
```

Comment: Please format you code and explain what additional value your answer brings to other answers

Comment: If you want to count unique words you can use sets. Simply it is `len(set(a.split()))`

Answer (score 0):

We can count the number of a word's ocurrence in a list using the `Counter` function.

```
from collection import Counter

string = ["mahesh","hello","nepal","nikesh","mahesh","nikesh"]

count_each_word = Counter(string)
print(count_each_word)
```

Output:

> Counter({mahesh:2},{hello:1},{nepal:1},{nikesh:2})

Comment: `from collections` - mind the **S** and the end

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:

You can clean your data first and then count the result, something like that:

```
mylist = ["Mahon Point retail park", "Finglas","Blackpool Mahon", "mahon point  blanchardstown"] 
for item in mylist:
    for char in "-.,":
        item = item.replace(char, '')
        item_word_list = item.split()
    print(len(item_word_list))
```

The result:

```
4
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ["Mahon Point retail park", "Finglas","Blackpool Mahon", "mahon point blanchardstown"]
flage = True
for string1 in mylist:
    n = 0
    for s in range(len(string1)):
        if string1[s] == ' ' and flage == False:
            n+=1
        if string1[s] == ' ':
            flage = True
        else:
            flage = False
    print(n+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista="Write a Python function to count the number of occurrences of a given characte Write a  of occurrences of a given characte"

dic=lista.split(" ")
wcount={} 
for i in dic:
  if i  in wcount:
    wcount[i]+=1
  else:
    wcount[i]=1 
print(wcount)
```

[picture with solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XirG2.png)