# Loop through every character in a sentence in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop

So I need to loop through a sentence character by character and total up the different letters and how many times they occur. I can't think of a way of doing the first bit (I'll do the totalling up myself I have a good enough idea and I'd like to see if I can do it solo).
I'm not top notch at Python but I assume it'll be a

```
for letter in sentence
```

but I'm not sure how to loop through each letter.

Comment: Do you mean through each word? You can't iterate over `"a"` (well you can, but it would be a bit pointless).

Comment: possible duplicate of [item frequency count in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly -- you have it right, `for letter in sentence:` is the correct way to loop through each character (though using the Counter class as mentioned below is the direct solution for what you're trying to do)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from `collections` (Python 2.7+):

```
>>> import collections
>>> sentence = "asdadasdsd"
>>> collections.Counter(sentence)
Counter({'d': 4, 'a': 3, 's': 3})
```

You can get the counts as follows:

```
>>> counts = collections.Counter(sentence)
>>> counts['d']
4
```

Comment: neat solution; please add him a spoiler tag, he wants to try on his own (:

Answer (score 2):

Well, the other solution tells you a clean way to do the job in two lines.  I however am going to answer your *real* question on how to loop through a sentence.

Truth is, you are right.  That is exactly how you loop through a sentence.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> sentence = "This is a sentence!"
>>> for letter in sentence:
...     print letter
...
T
h
i
s

i
s

a

s
e
n
t
e
n
c
e
!
>>>
```