# Fastest way to count the occurance of a string

Tags: python

I'm counting some string which i'm getting from text file. I have done that already but I want to know is there any other way that i can find quickly.
Below is my code:-

Here first I'm finding all the string and putting all these in a list. Then I'm making a list of unique query then after I'm using the count method to find the count.

**input.txt**

```
shoes
memory card
earphones
led bulb
mobile
earphones
led bulb
mobile
```

above is my input file.

```
new = []
with open("input.txt") as inf:
for line in inf:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    new.append(line)
unique = list(set(new))
for i in unique:
   cnt = new.count(i)
   print i,cnt
```

and output should look like this:

```
   mobile 2
   memory card 1
   led bulb 2
   shoes 1
   earphones 2
```

Comment: Example of input data? you have a single word in each line or something?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python Check this out for another solutions like collections.defaultdict or itertools.groupby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use counter:

```
from collections import Counter        

with open("input.txt") as inf:
   c = Counter(l.strip() for l in inf)
```

Gives:

```
Counter({'led bulb': 2, 'earphones': 2, 'mobile': 2, 'memory card': 1, 'shoes': 1})
```

or

```
for k,v in c.items():
    print(k,v)
```

which gives:

```
memory card 1
mobile 2
earphones 2
led bulb 2
shoes 1
```

Comment: hi @Marcin! with your answer, `with open("input.txt") as inf:c = Counter(l.strip() for l in inf)` `print(c)`  why do I have the word counter when I print (c)? `Counter({'joyeux': 4, 'amour': 2, 'hello': 1})`

Comment: What do you mean? isn't what you want? if not, please provide  example of your input data and expected output, Otherwise is a guessing game.

Comment: @s_m I updated the answer and it gives the results you expect. So i think its ok?

Answer (score 1):

Much better would be just counting them as they come in using a dictionary:

```
count = {}
for L in open("input.txt"):
    count[L] = count.get(L, 0) + 1
```

and you end up with a dictionary from lines to their respective counts.

The `count` method is fast because it's implemented in C, but still has to scan the full list for each unique string, so your implementation is O(n^2) (consider the worst case of having all strings distinct).