# How to sum values of tuples that have same name in Python

Tags: python, sum, tuples

I have the following list containing tuples that have to values:

```
mylist=[(3, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```

Is there a way to sum all values that share the same name?
Something like:

```
(9, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c')
```

I tried iterating tuples with for loop but can't get what i want.

Thank you

Comment: Could you show your attempt at iterating?  This isn't hard unless you are trying to get extremely pythonic.

Comment: I lost the code I was working with on IDLE, because I was just making some attempts. Anyway, i must have used some for loop to find any similarity (like if x == x) but it didn't work.

I'm sorry if you find my question stupid, I'm really new in Python though :)

Comment: Use Microsoft Excel pivot tables ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (after sorting by the second value of each tuple) to create groups. Then for each group, sum the first element in each tuple, then create a tuple per group in a list comprehension.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [(sum(i[0] for i in group), key) for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(mylist, key = lambda i: i[1]), lambda i: i[1])]
[(9, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c')]
```

Comment: Thank you, this just worked fine. I preferred to use some more "pythonic" way, but this seems just the best option to me. Thank you

Comment: using `sorted` with `groupyby` is wrong performance-wise. The proper way is to us a defaultdict

Answer (score 4):

Use a dict (or defaultdict) to aggregate over your tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist=[(3, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
sums = defaultdict(int)
for i, k in mylist:
    sums[k] += i   

print sums.items()
# output: [('a', 9), ('c', 5), ('b', 3)]

# Or if you want the key/value order reversed and sorted by key
print [(v, k) for (k, v) in sorted(sums.items())]
# output: [(9, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c')]
```

Comment: The output is not what the OP desired.

Comment: I specifically answered the question "Is there a way to sum all values that share the same name?". I thought it was trivial to reverse key/values in a list, but I updated my example to include that (and to have them sorted as well).

Comment: I don't really care about order of key/values in list. Thank you for your suggestion, it helped me understanding better Python.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach without any dependencies:

```
mylist = [(3, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b')]

sums = {}
for a, b in mylist:
    if b not in sums: sums[b] = a
    else: sums[b] += a

print list(sums.items())
```

Comment: Thank you, I like you suggestion. But it gives me

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1223>", line 6, in <module>
    print (list(sums.item()))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item'

What I'm not getting?

Comment: Seems like you made a typo, try `sums.items()` with an `s`.

Comment: @Niccolò: Sure you wrote "items" and not "item"?!

Comment: Yes, you were right, my bad! I typed item without the "s".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `dict` which has sum of individual keys.

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for item in mylist:
...     my_dict[item[1]] = my_dict.get(item[1], 0) + item[0]
>>> [(my_dict[k], k) for k in my_dict]
[(9, 'a'), (5, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
```