# how can I create word count output in python just by using reduce function?

Tags: python, list, tuples, reduce, word-count

I have the following list of tuples: `[('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c',1), ('a', 1), ('c', 1)]`

I would like to know if I can utilize python's `reduce` function to aggregate them and produce the following output : `[('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]`

Or if there are other ways, I would like to know as well (loop is fine)

Comment: Unless you're doing it concurrently, the best way is to use a HashMap with <tuple[0], frequency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum values of tuples that have same name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430384/how-to-sum-values-of-tuples-that-have-same-name-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

It seems difficult to achieve using `reduce`, because if both tuples that you "reduce" don't bear the same letter, you cannot compute the result. How to reduce `('a',1)` and `('b',1)` to some viable result?

Best I could do was `l = functools.reduce(lambda x,y : (x[0],x[1]+y[1]) if x[0]==y[0] else x+y,sorted(l))`

it got me `('a', 3, 'b', 1, 'c', 1, 'c', 1)`. So it kind of worked for the first element, but would need more than one pass to do the other ones (recreating tuples and make another similar `reduce`, well, not very efficient to say the least!).

Anyway, here are 2 working ways of doing it

First, using `collections.Counter` counting elements of the same kind:

```
l = [('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c',1), ('a', 1), ('c', 1)]

import collections

c = collections.Counter()
for a,i in l:
    c[a] += i
```

We cannot use listcomp because each element has a weight (even if here it is 1)

Result: a dictionary: `Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1})`

Second option: use `itertools.groupby` on the sorted list, grouping by name/letter, and performing the sum on the integers bearing the same letter:

```
print ([(k,sum(e for _,e in v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(l),key=lambda x : x[0])])
```

result:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative approach using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) subclass and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) function:

```
import collections

l = [('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c',1), ('a', 1), ('c', 1)]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for t in l:
    d[t[0]].append(t[1])

result = [(k,sum(v)) for k,v in d.items()]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('b', 1), ('a', 3), ('c', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is that to create your custom reduce function.
for example:
l = [('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c',1), ('a', 1), ('c', 1)]

```py
def myreduce(func , seq):
    output_dict = {}
    for k,v in seq:
        output_dict[k] = func(output_dict.get(k,0),v)
    return output_dict
```

myreduce((lambda sum,value:total+sum),l)

output:
{'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

later on you can modify the generated output as a list of tuples.