# using chunksize in pandas to read large size csv files that wont fit into memory

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a big size csv file using pandas that will not fit in the memory and create word frequency from it, my code works when the whole file fits inside the memory but when defining the chunk size it does not check the previous chunk to know if the word is there just increase the frequency of it if the word is not there just append it to the end of the file. it does each chunk separately regardless of what is inside the previous chunk, the code I'm trying is

```
dic = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip, chunksize=1):
    dic_tmp = (chunk['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='freq'))
    dic_tmp.append(dic)
dic.to_csv('nenene.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

for testing purpose I put the chunksize one for a small csv file which looks like :

[image]

the output Im getting is :

[image]

while what I'm trying to get is something like this:

[image]

I'm I doing something wrong in the code? any advice, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply groupby your created df:

Input:

```
   word  freq
0   fly     3
1  Alex     1
2  name     1
0  Alex     1
1   fly     1
```

---

```
df.groupby('word').sum()
```

---

Output:

```
       freq
word      
Alex     2
fly      4
name     1
```

---

Full example:

```
dic = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip, chunksize=1):
    dic_tmp = (chunk['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='freq'))
    dic = dic.append(dic_tmp)
dic = dic.groupby('word').sum().reset_index().sort_values('freq',ascending=False)
dic.to_csv('nenene.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: what if my code is creating the headers for each chunk ? how can I deal with them in that way ?

Comment: do you mean header in your saved csv?

Comment: only one time on the top yes called words and frequency

Comment: i edited my answer. i dont know about the column names that are created. you might have to change it a bit

Comment: that is what it gives me 3
2
3
2
1
3
2
2
1
5
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
3
3
1

Comment: i think this is just the frequency the words are not showen

Comment: @programmingfreak i edited my answer. add `.reset_index()`

Comment: thanks any function to sort them as well ? depending on freq?

Comment: also add `.sort_values('freq',ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake at `dic_tmp.append(dic)`, what you need is `dic = dic.append(dic_tmp)`. Also, You are getting the indices set by pandas in your output befor the words, you can do `index=False` parameter in your to_csv() function.

Comment: even with that is passing empty dataframs o dic for some reason

Comment: @programmingfreak My bad, I have updated the answer, please check that

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you wanna be doing:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip, chunksize=chunksize)
d = pd.concat(chunks)
d2 = d['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='freq')
```

avoiding unwanted loops will speed up your code as well when you read in large files

Comment: this does give me the output I want for the test result but when I try large csv file with it it gives error MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.03 TiB for an array with shape (1863448, 149437) and data type object
which I had before that is why I used for loops

Comment: In that case I will suggest collecting all counts separately in a list (chunk by chunk) and performing a reduce operation in the end. The reduce operation should consolidate the counts obtained by all the chunks. Helpful link for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172488/how-can-i-create-word-count-output-in-python-just-by-using-reduce-function

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the frequencies in each chunk.

Instead, you can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) for this. Create a counter object at the beginning. In each chunk update your counter via its `update` method. At the end, write down the output of `counter.most_common()` to a file as you wish.

**Update:**
An example of this is:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([]) # initiate counter with an empty list so we can update it later

chunks = pd.read_csv("/home/emre/Desktop/hdd/foo.csv", chunksize=1)

for chunk in chunks:
    for i, row in chunk.iterrows():
        c.update(row['sentences'].split(' '))

print(c.most_common())
```

The output is:

```
[('fly', 4),
 ('alex', 2),
 ('ibrahim', 2),
 ('hi', 1),
 ('my', 1),
 ('name', 1),
 ('is', 1),
 ('i', 1),
 ('am', 1),
 ('how', 1),
 ('are', 1),
 ('you', 1),
 ('doing', 1)]
```

Now you can iterate over this most commons and save them to a file:

```py
with open('most_commons.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for word_freq in c.most_common():
        f.write(word_freq[0] + ' ' + str(word_freq[1]) + '\n')
```

The file:

```
fly 4
alex 2
ibrahim 2
hi 1
my 1
name 1
is 1
i 1
am 1
how 1
are 1
you 1
doing 1
```

And in this way you don't have to make `chunksize=1`. Make it like `chunksize=1000` so it won't have to read the file from disk too many times.

Also writing to file part might be written more elegantly; it's just for demonstration.

Comment: can you give me an example code for my case please so I understand more what will happen

Comment: i put chunksize one for an example here just to demo I do use chunksize 10000 in the large dataset. I will try this code looks interesting thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

what was your dessision to use pandas?

maybe you can read the file line by line and update the collections counter every time.

```
import collections

freq = collections.Counter()
with open(filename) as f:
  for line in f:
    freq.update(line.split())
```

after this python block you will have the frequenze in varibale freq

Comment: because pandas can handle different operations for dealing with large data set sizes, I need to remove punctuation tokenize and all other things and pandas do offer all of them, how can I save the output of this code to another csv to see if its correct ?

Comment: you can convert it to a pandas dataframe and save the dataframe as csv:

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(freq), orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"word",0:"freq"}).to_csv(...)