# count the frequency of occurrence of a specific word on a webpage using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have tried to use this:

```
c=requests.get('https://www.uniberg.com/referenzen.html').text
c.count('Programmierung')
```

But the output shows 2 occurances while there are actually none.

Also I tried this:

```
a=requests.get('https://www.uniberg.com/index.html').text.count('Mitarbeiter')
```

but it also returns the count of words like `Mitarbeiterphilosophie` which I don't want.
Can someone find a way to improve this or suggest another method?

Comment: `<p class="detail">Design und Architektur einer OpenStack-Umgebung zur Integration einer virtualisierten IMS Open Source LÃ¶sung. Aufbau, Integration und Installation. Programmierung und Automatisierung der funktionalen Erweiterungen zur Integration in die Rechenzentrums-Infrastruktur insbesondere hinsichtlich Deployment und Skalierung.</p>`

Comment: What made you think there are no occurrences?

Comment: Use NLTK to find the count https://www.reddit.com/r/pythontips/comments/4mu9qq/word_count_using_text_mining_module_nltk_natural/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [item frequency count in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today `https://www.uniberg.com/referenzen.html` contanins 2  occurances `Programmierung`

I think, you need check in HTML source code, not in the render using a browser.

The words `Programmierung` are on HTML section with this `CSS`

```
section .detail {
    display: none;
}
```

For the second point :

try this (using `regex`) :

```
import re
len(re.findall(r'\WMitarbeiter\W', requests.get('https://www.uniberg.com/index.html').text))
```

With regex :

- `\w` stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_].
- `\W` is short for `[^\w]`, the negated version of `\w`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for the second point, still looking for a solution to the first

Answer (score 0):

requests.get(URL) returns the entire Web-page(look at it with ctrl+U on Google-Chrome or just use wget to download the webpage) and not just what is rendered by web browser.That's why count is showing up as 2.