# Random Numbers in Excel into percentage

Tags: python

Hi my code works fine but is there any way to print how many times numbers 1-6 were said into a percentage

I haven't tried anything yet.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [random.randint(0,6) for _ in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df.to_excel(r'H:\Grade10\Cs\Mir Hussain 12.00.00 3.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: 1-6 each individually or as a group compared to 0?

Comment: individually I want it to say how many times 1 was said then 2 than 3 than 4 than 5 than 6 0 is not  needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your data you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from collections import Counter


data = [random.randint(0,6) for _ in range(10)]
total_data = [data]

frequency = Counter(data)
number_elements = len(data)

total_data.append(list((frequency[item] / number_elements)*100 if item != 0 else '' for item in total_data[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame(total_data)

print(df)

df.to_excel(r'H:\Grade10\Cs\Mir Hussain 12.00.00 3.xlsx', index=False)
```

[Item frequency count in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893417/item-frequency-count-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [random.randint(0,6) for _ in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.value_counts(normalize=True) # this line makes the percentages

df.to_excel(r'H:\Grade10\Cs\Mir Hussain 12.00.00 3.xlsx', index=False)
```